# Java 2d array of objects

Tags: java

I have a cell object with function

```
public class Cell {
    static int X;
    static int Y;
    static int Val = 0;
    static int Player = 0;

    public Cell(int a, int b, int p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        X = a;
        Y = b;
        Val = 0;
        Player = p;
    }
```

With additional function updateX, updateY, updateVal, updatePlayer and respective get functions. It is called by

```
    Cell[][] grid = new Cell[7][6];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, 0);         
            }       
        System.out.println("wasd");
        grid[0][1].updatePlayer(1); 
        grid[0][1].updateVal(1);

        System.out.println("grid[0][1].getval = " + grid[0][1].getVal() + " grid[1][1].getval = " + grid[1][1].getVal());
```

But the output is

```
grid[0][1].getval = 1 grid[1][1].getval = 1
```

and should be

```
grid[0][1].getval = 1 grid[1][1].getval = 0
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Don't use static variables and methods unless you've got good reason for doing so -- you don't and as a matter of fact have strong reason for *not* doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int X;
static int Y;
static int Val = 0;
static int Player = 0;
```

These properties should not be static,following code should be ok:

```
int X;
int Y;
int Val;//the default int value is zero 
int Player;
```

Answer (score 2):

You made the X, Y, Val and Player variables in the class static. Which means they are shared by all instances of that class, which means their values in all those instances will be exactly the same. I'm pretty sure you wanted to declare those as **instance** variables instead:

```
public class Cell {
    private int x, y, val, player;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's not just the x and y fields -- he's made ***all*** the fields static when ***none*** should be.

Answer (score 2):

You made `Val` a static variable, so only one `Val` variable exists and it is shared by all `Cell` objects.

change:

```
static int Val = 0;
```

to:

```
int Val = 0;
```

Similarly if you want individual `Cell` objects to retain separate instances of your variables (i.e. x,y,Val) you need to take away the `static` keyword from all of them